# How to download an email from gmail

Tags: gmail, pop3, rebol, rebol2

I am trying to make small mailbox with REBOL/Command, but I cannot connect with my gmail account because the pop server is accessed through SSL on port 995.

```
>> pop: open/lines ssl://pop.gmail.com:995
>> set-modes pop [secure: true]
>> print first pop
+OK Gpop ready for requests from 213.240.224.162 7mb34713954eem
>> insert pop "user ******@gmail.com"
>> print first pop
+OK send PASS
>> insert pop "pass password"
>> print first pop
+OK Welcome.
```

I try to connect with server with this code, but I receive error message:

```
>> port: open/lines ssl://pop.gmail.com:995
>> set-modes port [secure: true]
>> mailbox: open pop://
connecting to: pop.gmail.com
** User Error: Server error: tcp connection failed
** Near: mailbox: open pop://
>> mailbox: open pop://:995
connecting to: pop.gmail.com
** User Error: Server error: tcp connection failed
** Near: mailbox: open pop://:995
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://re-bol.com/prot-spop.r for the spop protocol for rebol/command.

I also have a version for Rebol3 somewhere.  R3 from Saphir/Atronix has https.

Answer (score 0):

The pop scheme does not support ssl. You could try to write your own pop scheme with ssl. I guess Graham Chiu did that once.